# Vertical align Span within Div

Tags: html, css

I have the below code running to create three columns centered in the middle of the screen. The problem I have is when I add varying amounts of content to each span, one ends up much higher than the other two. The background on the main page is black and each span is white.

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center; min-width:1200px;">
<span style="display: inline-block; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#fff; ">
        Content
</span>
<span style="display: inline-block; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#fff;">
        Content
</span>

<span style="display: inline-block; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#fff; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
        Content blah blah blah
</span>
</div>
```

How can I make it so all of the spans are the same vertical position. I have setup the height as all the same values

Comment: Have you tried wrapping all `<span>`s and positioning that element in the middle instead so the wrapper expands with the highest `<span>`?

Comment: what exactly is ur requirement can you post the image of your desired result...............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">

body{
background:black;
}

.mydiv{
margin-left:100px;
width:300px;
float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div style="width:100%; text-align:center; min-width:1200px;">

<div class="mydiv"><span style="display: inline-block; width:300px; background-  color:#fff; ">
       blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah  blahblah blah blah
</span></div>
<div class="mydiv"><span style="display: inline-block; width:300px; background-color:#fff;">
        Hello Wolrd!blah blah blahblah blah blah
</span>
</div>
<div class="mydiv"><span style="display: inline-block; width:300px; background-color:#fff; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
        Content blah blah blah
</span></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

css property `display: table-cell;vertical-align:middle` will center the block vertically.

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center; min-width:1200px;">
<span style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        Content
</span>
<span style=" width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#fff; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        Content
</span>

<span style=" width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#fff; margin:0px; padding:0px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        Content blah blah blah
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For modern browsers you can use the [`columns` <sup>W3C docs</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#introduction) css property.

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="columns">
      All content
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    min-width:1200px;
    background-color:black;
}
.columns{
    -moz-columns:300px 3;
    -webkit-columns:300px 3;
    columns:300px 3;
    width:900px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:white;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/b2fNk/1